# What is the maximum Duration in Java Akka API?

Tags: java, akka, duration, openjdk-11

I'm working with the Akka Java library (unfortunately, the Classic version). When implementing the fault tolerance Strategy, the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fault-tolerance.html#creating-a-supervisor-strategy) provide a snippet like this:

```java
private static SupervisorStrategy strategy =
    new OneForOneStrategy(
        10,
        Duration.ofMinutes(1),        // <----- Note here!
        DeciderBuilder.match(...)
                      .build();
```

Moreover, it says:
"Also, there are special values for these parameters. If you specify:
`-1` to `maxNrOfRetries`, and `Duration.Inf()` to `withinTimeRange`, then the child is always restarted without any limit".
The problem is that, in my Java (openjdk-11), **`Duration.Inf()` doesn't actually exist!**.

I have read some SO answers that specify what is the effective maximum Duration, but Akka seem to not recognize them. The best I could do is to specify `Duration.ofNanos(Long.MAX_VALUE)`.

Am I missing something? Is there actually a value to input or is the Akka documentation just wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Duration.Inf()` there isn't referring to `java.time.Duration` (even though the snippet above that in the docs does use the Java `Duration` API).  Under the hood, Akka converts the Java `Duration` to a `scala.concurrent.duration.Duration`, which does have an `Inf` (the naming pattern indicates that it's a constant in Scala) which is defined to be greater than any `FiniteDuration`).  The Java API just has a constructor which takes `java.time.Duration`.

This should work:

```java
new OneForOneStrategy(
    10,
    scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf(),
    true,  // have to explicitly pass the default loggingEnabled
    DeciderBuilder.match(...).build()
);
```

The maximum value of a Java `Duration` is `Duration.ofSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE).plusNanos(999999999)`.  Note that inside Akka, when converted to Scala `Duration` this will be considered less than an infinite duration, but that *probably* doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I'll send a note t the team so they can clarify the docs. Just a thing: even without passing `loggingEnabled`, it works, there's a constructor for that (it's not necessary, and it defaults to `true`). Btw, I didn't noticed this parameter, you're saving me a lot of screen clutter. Thanks!